# Thread runs only one time

Tags: android, multithreading

Here is my code.

```
public void showCallFragment(){

        address_phone = new ArrayList<>();
           Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    OyumDataBaseHelper dbh = new OyumDataBaseHelper(Address_Activity.this);

                    dbh.OpenDatabase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < addressIds.size(); i++) {
                        Cursor cr1 = dbh.getPhone(addressIds.get(i));

                        cr1.moveToFirst();

                        ArrayList<String> phoneList = new ArrayList<>();

                        do {
        phoneList.add(cr1.getString(cr1.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.ph_phone_number)));

                        } while (cr1.moveToNext());

                        address_phone.add(phoneList);

                        cr1.close();

                    }

                }
            });

            thread1.start();
    }
```

This function is being called from the OnCreate(Bundle) method. I am using a listview in my activity each of which open a dialogFragment on their onClick function. The problem is when I go back to previous activity, and open my listview activity, this time there is an error on their onClick function. The function showDialogFragment() runs but thread is not working at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to this hope this can help you..

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
           //your code here
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
   thread1.start();
```

Comment: Great! This solution worked, although I couldn't get how?

Comment: @ Yo'dilawar , You miss the sleep function..and please also upvote this answer...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that:

1) when you go to previous Activity, onResume() method is called (and not again the onCreate() method in which your method is launched). So the function won't start again.

2)the thread doesn't go with the main thread which is the one which regulates the activity life cycle. This means that the thread which is started continues its loop until all the executions are completed, then it stops. Its life cycle doesn't depend on the one of the various Activities.

So I think the thread stops and when you go back, it's not launched again.

Answer (score 0):

It is not considered a best practice to use a *Thread* for situations like what you have in there. Instead you could use a simple AsyncTask:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
static class  GrabAddressesTask extends   AsyncTask<SQLiteOpenHelper,Void, List<String>>{

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(SQLiteOpenHelper... params) {
        final List<String> addresses=new ArrayList<>();
        final SQLiteDatabase db=params[0].getReadableDatabase();
        try{
            // get your addresses here and update the List
        }
        finally {
            db.close();
        }
        return addresses;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> stringList) {
        super.onPostExecute(stringList);
        // update your UI in here
        // make sure you do not keep a strong reference to you Activity/Fragment in this class
        // if you need a reference just use a WeakReference
    }
}
```

And the way you can use it:

```
new GrabAddressesTask().execute(sqlOpenHelper);
```